# CMake Error at C:\Users\...\Desktop\imgwarp-opencv\imgwarp-opencv\src\CMakeLists.txt:2 (FIND_PACKAGE)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, visual-c++, cmake

I am using Window 10, Visual Studio 2017. I have installed OpenCV properly and I can run some basic projects of C++ OpenCV that can be found around the internet.
I have also followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxHV-KNEG3k) which shows *How to Build Open Source Projects Using CMake and Visual Studio*.

But, I can not run [this project](https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv) on my machine. I try **File->Open->CMake** to open the **CMakeLists.txt** which can be found in the downloaded repository, and I get this error:

[image: CMake Error]

```
CMake Error at C:\Users\Majid\Desktop\imgwarp-opencv\imgwarp-opencv\src\CMakeLists.txt:2 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I think I must extract the downloaded **opencv-4.0.1-vc14_vc15.exe** file somewhere in the project folder and link the **CMakeLists.txt** file (which one?) to the **OpenCVConfig.cmake** which is in the extracted opencv. Or maybe not.

I have also **CMake gui** and if I should run it that way I will appreciate that you explain it that way instead of using Visual Studio **File->Open->CMake**. No matter how, any way that helps me run this project is welcome. Please explain it step by step.

**In one line (forget all the above):** What should I do to run [this project](https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv) properly?

Comment: "What should I do to run this project properly?" - Ask its developer about this. The project's `CMakeLists.txt` lacks for `cmake_minimum_required` call, which causes at least warning on any new CMake.

Comment: As for searching for OpenCV, you definitely need OpenCV installed with its `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file. Then find installation directory of OpenCV. When build your project, in CMake GUI create `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` cache entry (of type STRING, or PATH) and set its value to the directory with OpenCV installation. Or find location of `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file on your machine, and assign this location to the `OpenCV_DIR` cache entry. BTW, this is what is written in the error message.

Comment: I have [asked its developer](https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv/issues/5) as an issue but he says that he does not have time to write more document.
And yes, as the error says, I can find the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` on my machine but do not know where is `OpenCV_DIR` and how should I link it to the project. Should I modify the `CMakeLists.txt`?
Could you please try running this project yourself? And tell me what should I do to run this properly? I really appreciate that.

Comment: `OpenCV_DIR` is a CMake cache entry. Please, re-read my previous comment, it explains how to set this entry.

Comment: How should I build the project, and after that which folder should I assign to the source code in CMake GUI? (God bless python!)

Comment: As you build the project directly from Visual Studio, you don't need to use CMake GUI instead - Visual Studio already provides needed user interface. You may find CMake cache entries in menu `CMake` / `Cache` / `View CMakeCache`.

Comment: I have changed that file into `OpenCV_DIR:PATH=C:\Users\Majid\Desktop\imgwarp-opencv\imgwarp-opencv\src\opencv\build\OpenCVConfig.cmake`, but still get the same error when I `Generate` it.

In the repository, there are different `CMakeLists.txt` in each folder. Which one should I Generate?

Comment: There is one is `src` folder, one in `demo` folder and one in `lib` folder.

Comment: `OpenCV_DIR` should contain **directory**, not a *file*. Also, as it is CMake variable, it should use "generic" path separator, not a one used by Windows itself. Assign `C:/Users/Majid/Desktop/imgwarp-opencv/imgwarp-opencv/src/opencv/build` to that variable.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I should have used a **directory**. Now, I get this error:
`CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1313 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x`.

I think now I must install Qt and deal with that, right?

Comment: Yes, install QT.

Comment: Sorry for the continuous questions. I have installed Qt, and I should change this line in `CMakeLists.txt` which is `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=NOTFOUND` but I can not the executable Qt file in the installed directory of CMake which is `C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\templates\wizards\projects\qmake`. In the `qmake` folder there is a folder called `empty` and in the `empty` folder there are two files: `file.pro` and `wizard.json`. I installed the default open source Qt from its website.

Comment: Wait, you need OpenCV, not QT. For work with OpenCV, you need to install it completely, not just to copy its `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file. After installing OpenCV, find its `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file, and set `OpenCV_DIR` to point to this file. **Do not copy** file `OpenCVConfig.cmake` - it should be located exactly where it is installed with OpenCV. In other places this file doesn't work.

Comment: I did not copy anything, I just linked the folder containing `OpenCVConfig.cmake` to the `OpenCV_DIR` variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, and after generating the code one more time, got a new error about not finding Qt.